# Ruby string returns with slashes

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to create a server. Here is what I have:

```
def server_root 
  @hash_httpd['ServerRoot'].gsub(/''/,"")
end
```

There are problems. This is an rspec message:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(httpd_file.document_root).to eq 'document_root'

   expected: "document_root"
        got: "\"document_root\""

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/lib/config/httpd_conf_spec.rb:30:in `(root)'
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the format of `@hash_httpd['ServerRoot']`, but you could try `gsub(/"/,"")`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is not with slashes but with double quotes.

If you need to delete the double quotes, then change to:

```
@hash_httpd['ServerRoot'].gsub(/"/, '')
```

or just:

```
@hash_httpd['ServerRoot'].gsub('"', '')
```

Comment: Or `@hash_httpd['ServerRoot'].delete('"')`.

Comment: but why is it \ instead of /

Comment: @KevinHwang If you have quotes inside quotes, then you have to use back slash \  to escape the inside quotes, right?

Comment: Ohhhhh ok, but can you sort of explain gsub two parameter? I can't really understand the gsub documentation from ruby page

Comment: It replaces every instance of the first parameter(regex or string) with the second parameter(string). In this case it replaces all double quotes with the empty string.